# Stop web pages from disabling shortcuts in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript

How can I stop a web site from taking over my browser?

Example: When I visit a web site, it blocks my keyboard short cuts such as copy and paste.

I want to use these short cuts when I need them.

Answer (score 4):

Disable JavaScript.

Comment: the simplest solution, yet effective. However, disabling JavaScript may cause other functions stop working.

Comment: Don't forget to disable flash as well.

Comment: And images, to prevent XSRF attacks, you can never be too safe!

Answer (score 1):

If there is a specific site you use a lot that does this, you could use a Greasemonkey script to re-enable the thing they took out, but I don't think that is a general solution.

Comment: Greasemonkey? On Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes http://www.gm4ie.com/

Comment: Nice. Didn't know of that one so far.